# Laravel Redis php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known [tcp://redis:6379]

Tags: laravel-5, redis, docker-container

Server throwing below error may be on heavy site traffic or loss of redis connection.
But unable to found the cause of this error that can help to resolve.

Also server stops due to below errors at specific UK time around every day at 4 AM.

So any help regarding this will be helpful.

```
Server : Digital Ocean
Frontend : React JS
Backend : laravel (5.8)
Used spiritix/lada-cache library for mysql cashing to manage large amount of data.
Application is running on Docker containers.
```

> 1) error:
>
> production.ERROR: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name
>   or service not known [tcp://redis:6379] {"exception":"[object]
>   (Predis\Connection\ConnectionException(code: 0):
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not
>   known [tcp://redis:6379] at
>   /var/www/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:155)
>
> 2) error :-
>
> Redis - LOADING Redis is loading the dataset in memory:
>
> 3) error :-
>
> production.ERROR: Connection refused [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]

This error will stops the server as well.

I have tried to restart docker down containers on cron scheduler. But the actual issue is not with docker container, some internal laravel packages like Predis | Ladacash throwing above error for that unable to find exact solution.

Answer (score 9):

Since you are using docker, you no longer should refer to your redis server (docker container) using an IP (say 127.0.0.1). Instead use the container name.

1) Run: `docker ps` to list all containers, then find the redis server, and copy and paste the name under `container name` column to your `.env` file as the host.

2) Make sure that both your app container and redis container are in the same network:

```
docker network ls
docker network inspect <network_name>
```

Comment: For temp solution have added cron usign shell script to restart redis docker container.

Comment: If I add container name in .env, it stops the running server.

Comment: I had to user 0.0.0.0, the container name or 127.0.0.1 didn't work

Comment: In my case, I missed the Laradock Redis container:  `$ docker-compose up -d redis`

Comment: This saved me. I forgot to add redis to the network that PHP and Nginx were.

Answer (score 1):

A bit irrelevant as it could be a lot of causes to this problem but in my 2 cases I've solved this problem by:

1. Reloading my .env: clear the cache: `php artisan config:cache` and reloads the env file into cache: `php artisan config:clear`
2. My Docker service was actually down on one of my Docker Swarm nodes (a worker in this case) so restarting my node / server restarted Docker which restarted my PHP-FPM container that was "broken" and not communicating with the Redis container on my Manager node anymore